# Tie SharePoint list, Active Directory group and forum together

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

We are using Microsoft Exchange together with Active Directory and MOSS 2007.

**I want to accomplish the following:**

Interest groups defined already in AD and used as Mailing Lists inside Exchange. How can we create a site in SharePoint for this Interest group and at the same time have a Forum inside that SharePoint site which also reflects the conversations done in the Exchange mailling list.

I was thinking if the forum could be a list, then the list could somehow subscribe to the Exchange list and receive a copy of the conversation, and it would appear in the forum on the interest group.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: i guess the option you provided is wonderful.
Hope share point does that.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up inbound mail for SharePoint you can email enable a list including the discussion threads.  If you setup a forwarder to that email address the messages would be logged in the forum.

Here is a good article on inbound email - [SharePoint 2007 incoming email](http://blogs.msdn.com/neilth/archive/2007/10/26/sharepoint-2007-incoming-email.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your AD group to a SharePoint group so that when you update your AD group, the SharePoint group does not need to be edited.